# Trying to make a flexible UI

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments

I'am trying to make a app with a *flexible UI*.
I already implemented for handset devices (I have one activity and multiple **fragments**), and what I done was: The main fragment is a dashboard, and when I click in one button of it, he dashboard is replaced by a new fragment ( the clicked feature). Here is the code:

Dashboard fragment:

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

    GridView gridView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dashboard, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        gridView=(GridView)getView().findViewById(R.id.dashboard_grid);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Fragment fragment = null ;

                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new TestFragment();
                    break;
                case 1 :
                    fragment = new TestFragment();
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    fragment = new TestFragment();
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    fragment = new TestFragment();
                    break;
                case 4 :
                    fragment = new TestFragment();
                    break;
                }
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

and my Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (findViewById(R.id.container) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
            DashboardFragment firstFragment = new DashboardFragment();
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, firstFragment).commit();
        }
    }


}
```

Now, what I want is to adapt this code and use a layout for tablets, with the dashboard on the left and the choosen fragment on  the right, like this:

[image]

What could I do? I already tried to adapt [this](http://docs.huihoo.com/android/4.2/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) example, but I can't because they only update the fragment, they don't replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [great article about multi-pane development](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html).
It also includes an example (Sections 10 and 11)

Basically you can check whether there is a fragment element for your "Fragment B" in the current layout. If yes, you just update its content, if no, then start an activity which has it in its layout, or replace one in the current layout.

```
DetailFragment fragment = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);
if (fragment==null || ! fragment.isInLayout()) {
    // start new Activity or replace
}
else {
    fragment.update(...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gyebro, but I already tried that. I made a layout-large folder with a specific layout, and when I run I got "unfortunately, "app name" has stopped. And I can't figure out why.

Comment: Create a new project in Android Studio, add an activity and choose Master/Detail flow. This will generate an example with two fragments (master and detail) and different layouts for small and large screens. Then study that example.